# python-telegram-bot error inline : input message content is not specified

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I have a function that takes a string and searches it in the dictionary and then returns the result as a string. I searched a lot but I could not learn how to show the output of the function to the user using the inline method.
I use the python-telegram-bot library. This is the code I wrote to return the result of the response function.

```
def inlinequery(update, context: CallbackContext) :
    query = update.inline_query.query
    if query == "":
        return

    results = [
        InlineQueryResultArticle(
            id=str(uuid4()),
            title="find this class code",
            description='example 1322008',
            input_message_content=InputTextMessageContent(
                response(query)
            )
        )
    ]
    update.inline_query.answer(results)
```

I want the query result to be received as an inline bot. Sometimes it works but this error appears :

root - ERROR - Update {'inline_query': {'id': '701438966003659473', 'offset': '', 'query': '1322008', 'chat_type': 'private', 'from': {'is_bot': False, 'id': 1633163216, 'first_name': '*', 'username': '*', 'language_code': 'fa'}}, 'update_id': 331490925} caused error Can't parse inline query result: input message content is not specified

Comment: please show us the definition of the `rensponse` function

Comment: def response(code):
 if code.isdigit() and len(code) == 7:
  return f"{code} found"
 else:
  return f"{code} not found"

Comment: that looks okay, as it returns a string in any case. I also can't reproduce the problem. Can you show the full traceback? You'll have to deactivate your error handler for that, as it hides the traceback.

Comment: I'm sorry, I may not have done it right, but this is a mistake.  https://ibb.co/dJXGjtR

Comment: mh, this doesn't reveal anything either … then I'm sorry, but I don't know what's going wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with my response function, which sometimes returned None type ...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).